# Remove trailing string for date formatting

Tags: javascript, regex, string, momentjs

Im using [Moment Duration Format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) and its great. I just cannot get the right string format in some cases.

These are my current string output types are below

```
var dur = moment.duration(d, "minutes").format("h [hrs] m [min]");
```

1. 45 min
2. 1 hr 30 min
3. 2 hr 0 min

These are all correct outputs, I just want to be able to change the final type.

When hours are present and mins are **ZERO**, I want to trim the string to just show the hours

So

2 hr 0 min **becomes** 2 hr

I'm not sure where to start with regex ? I think that might be the only way to accomplish it ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: According to the documentation, you can use `{ trim: "right" }` as settings parameter to trim from right. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Doesn't help - I tried that. It returns values such as 0 hrs 45 min when there are no hours

Comment: I think the propper solution is to implement a better parser for moment's formatting system, but is way more complicated to do. Maybe replacing the `0 min` pattern could be an easier  solution or creating a different format for when minutes is different than zero.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I have updated my answer. Hope it covers most of the cases.

Comment: @DogCoffee Please check the updates in the answer. I have added handling for `sec` and `secs` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of regex, use a wrapper function that checks if object has value and if not, update the format string.

```js
function getFormattedString(duration) {
  var format = "";
  if (duration.hours()) format += "h [hrs] ";
  if (duration.minutes()) format += "m [min] "
  if (duration.seconds()) format += "s [sec] ";
  return duration.format(format)
}

console.log(getFormattedString(moment.duration(20, "minutes")))
console.log(getFormattedString(moment.duration(100, "minutes")))
console.log(getFormattedString(moment.duration(120, "minutes")))
console.log(getFormattedString(moment.duration(3701, "seconds")))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Updated Code (*generic wrapper*)

- Added options for `year`, `days` etc
- Added a static Map to make code generic
- Added handling for `1 sec` and `10 secs`.

```js
function getFormattedDurationString(value, unit) {
  const valueMap = [
    {name:'years', value:'y', unitValue:'yr'},
    {name:'days', value:'d', unitValue:'day'},
    {name:'hours', value:'h', unitValue:'hr'},
    {name:'minutes', value:'m', unitValue:'min'},
    {name:'seconds', value:'s', unitValue:'sec'},
    {name:'milliseconds', value:'s', unitValue:'ms', bypassPlural: true},
  ]

  var duration = moment.duration(value, unit);
  var format = valueMap.reduce(function(p,c){
  var val = duration[c.name]();
  if(val >0){
    p += c.value + " [" + c.unitValue +  (val > 1 && !c.bypassPlural ? "s":"") + "] ";
  }
  return p
}, "")
return duration.format(format)
}

console.log(getFormattedDurationString(20, "minutes"))
console.log(getFormattedDurationString(100, "minutes"))
console.log(getFormattedDurationString(120, "minutes"))
console.log(getFormattedDurationString(3701, "seconds"))
console.log(getFormattedDurationString(3701, "days"))
console.log(getFormattedDurationString(3701, "milliseconds"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you should put the original one up as well.

Comment: @DogCoffee Done. But I guess current code will cover lot more cases and also handles `sec` vs `secs` cases, so its more recommended.

Comment: Thanks for help - very nice answers.